# Help on video drivers

Tags: software-installation, gpu-driver

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 on my home PC. Installation proceeded with no problems at all, but now I'm having trouble with the video drivers.
The drive I need to install is SiS 671, v.7.14.10.5280, A01, I have the zip file downloaded, but is for windows.

When I go to configurations the drive used is a generic one, and no other option for choice.

I really need to install this driver, cause my screen isn't working very well with the generic one.

Clarification of the question: How to install SiS 671, v.7.14.10.5280, A01 driver on ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit or 32-bit CPU? If this page works for you, I'll compile it into an answer: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/sis

Comment: 64-bit, sorry for delay in aswering

Comment: There is no way to get proper resolution with this adapter on any Ubuntu version higher than 12.04. There are manuals how to install drivers for 12.04 around.

Comment: @Pilot6 well, if OP wants to use 2D-rendering only, yes, he can use 14.04

Comment: The screen resolution will be wrong anyway. Nothing better that 1024x768 with wrong proportions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple solution, posted here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2167879

Simple use the command:

`sudo cp xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

This creates a brand new `xorg.conf` file.

As a side note, there are no 3D drivers for SiS video cards in Ubuntu. This fix only applies to the 2D drivers. In short, you cannot use Unity and must use a lighter DE.

Even more, it is not recommended to even use SiS video cards with Ubuntu flavors **past 12.04.** From here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/AdvancedMethods#SIS_graphics

> SIS graphics
>   SIS graphics should be run with flavours or re-spins of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, for example Bento, Bodhi, LXLE.

(I recommend just getting either a new PC, or a new video card. There won't ever be 3D drivers for SiS cards in Linux, nor will there be continued support)